# Nuxt 3 custom string Interpolation using dynamic component

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, nuxt3

Hope you are all doing well. Just want to know if someone already tried to create their own interpolation using [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components). Already been fixing this for days but still can't figure it out.

```js
<template>
  <h4>Hi!</h4>
  <component
    :is="{
      template: dynamicTemp,
    }"
  />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const firstName = "Joe";
const useInputContent = "<h3>Welcome {name}</h3>";

// Replace {name} to "Joe"
const dynamicTemp = useInputContent.replace("{name}", firstName);
</script>
```

```
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
});
```

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

When I'm running that, I'm getting this warning: [Vue warn]: Component provided template option but runtime compilation is not supported in this build of Vue. Configure your bundler to alias "vue" to "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js".

Will really appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by enabling `experimental.runtimeVueCompiler` https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/20381